# how to improve Performance for this code?

Tags: performance, perl, file-io, runtime

this code is running on a file of 200M lines at least. and this takes a lot of time
I would like to know if I can improve the runtime of this loop.

```
    my @bin_lsit; #list of 0's and 1's
    while (my $line = $input_io->getline) {
        if ($bin_list[$i]) {    
            $line =~ s/^.{3}/XXX/;
        } else {
            $line =~ s/^.{3}/YYY/;
        } 


        $output_io->appendln($line);
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: never used it! can u tell me how ?

Comment: do you think $input_io and $output_io can fit into memory? Maybe you're wasting time in I/O

Comment: Disk I/O is going to be your bottleneck, so as long as you're reading and writing all 200M lines, I don't see any ways to speed this up significantly. What exactly are you trying to achieve? (not how, but *what*) Perhaps there's a better approach that doesn't require as much I/O.

Comment: $input_io and $output_io are just pointers.. memory usage is not my problem..

Comment: What is `$i`? What is it counting?

Comment: line counter.. $bin_list[$i]

Comment: If `input_io` is a member of a class that inherits from IO::Handle, then your use of `$i` may reproduce the functionality of the `input_line_number()` method...

Comment: still, $i++ is faster than calling a function..

Comment: Where does the list of 0s and 1s come from?

Comment: a binary file that I convert to list

Comment: Ahh, as you were using OO IO I assumed method calls would be OK for you.  I'm sure you're aware that `$.` and `input_line_number()` refer to the same thing. (also `$NR` & `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER` if you `use english;`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smallest change is probably to buffer between appendln's

```
my @bin_lsit; #list of 0's and 1's
my $i = 0;
while (my $line = $input_io->getline) {
    if ($bin_list[$i]) {    
        $line =~ s/^.{3}/XXX/;
    } else {
        $line =~ s/^.{3}/YYY/;
    } 

    $buffer .= $line;
    if ( $i % 1000 == 0 ) {
        $output_io->appendln($buffer);
        $buffer = '';
    }
    $i++;
}
if ( $buffer ne '' ) {
    $output_io->appendln($buffer);
}
```

Are you using IO::All?
I couldn't find anything else with appendln...

Replacing this:

```
my $input_io = io 'tmp.this';
my $output_io = io 'tmp.out';
while (my $line = $input_io->getline ) {
    $output_io->appendln($line);
}
```

With this:

```
open(IFH, 'tmp.this');
open(OFH, '>>tmp.out');
while (my $line = <IFH> ) {
    print OFH $line;
}
close IFH;
close OFH;
```

Is quite a bit faster (1 sec vs 23 in my test case).

Comment: I'm buffering lines into list. And yes, I'm using IO::ALL.
I'm running now my testcase to see if the last part of ur answer.

Answer (score 1):

A regex solution may be overkill here.  How about replacing the `if/else` blocks with:

`substr($line, 0, 3, $bin_list[$i] ? 'XXX' : 'YYY';`

Comment: its 10% faster.. good start.. now I want to know if it's possible to speed up the writing

Comment: @user3787639 Editing your question to include tjd's code completely invalidates this answer. Imagine if I asked, "I have a job. How can I make more money?" and somebody answered, "Get a job." The answer doesn't make sense. Please don't make edits like that.